# Angular2 (rc4) - Check active child route in parent component

Tags: typescript, angular, router

I am trying to check the active child route in a parent component, but I am having difficulties with it.

I have tried to subscribe to the ActivatedRoute by doing something like this:

```
class ParentComponent {
    constructor(private _route:ActivatedRoute) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this._route.data.subscribe(value => console.log(value)});
    }
}
```

I have read a lot of threads on Stack Overflow, but can't find a solution that checks and gets updated regarding the child routes of a parent component.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access active child route using below code snippet

```
constructor(private router:Router, private currentActivatedRoute:ActivatedRoute)
// this should be called in ngOnInit
    var state = this.router.routerState
    var children = state.children(this.currentActivatedRoute)
```

[RouterState](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-rc.4/modules/%40angular/router/src/router_state.ts#L17-L48), [Tree](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-rc.4/modules/%40angular/router/src/utils/tree.ts)

Comment: `Property 'children' does not exist on type 'RouterState'` ... :/

Comment: Not sure if something changed since this answer was posted, but children is a property of ActivatedRoute, NOT Router

Answer (score 4):

While writing these lines, the selected answer does not seem to work anymore.

If you want to be notified when a route change, you can subscribe to the `Router.events` observable. for example, `NavigationEnd` events store the url as a property:

```
 this.router.events.filter(evt => evt instanceof NavigationEnd)
                   .map(evt =>evt.url)
                   .subscribe(url=>console.log(url));
```

If you want to compare the current route to a child path -let's say `"child"`-. You can use the `Router.isActive()` method:

```
let events = this.router.events;
events.filter(evt => evt instanceof NavigationEnd)
       .map(() =>{
            let exact=true;
            let childRoute=this.router.createUrlTree(["child"], {relativeTo: this.route}
            return this.router.isActive(childRoute,exact);
        })
        .subscribe(active=>console.log(`child route is active :${active`));
```

Notes:

- `this.router` is a `Router` instance
- `this.route` is an instance of `ActivatedRoute`
- `exact` is used to make exact match : if the route was `"child/grand-child"` `this.router.isActive(route,true)` would return false

Comment: Getting this error .. `property 'url' does not exist on type 'Event'
property 'url' does not exist on type 'RouteConfigLoadStart'`

Comment: @Aakriti You need to filter router events and only take `NavigationEnd` events. `this.router.events.filter(evt => evt instanceof NavigationEnd)` (may be you need to assert type to be `Observable<NavigationEnd>` like this : `this.router.events.filter(evt => evt instanceof NavigationEnd) as Observable<NavigationEnd>`

Comment: How will we use map with this .. it is saying `cannot find name map`