# Angular 2: Have Child Route Component Replace Parent in router-outlet

Tags: angular

Is there a way to display a child route in the parent route's `<router-outlet>`?

For example, let's say we have two routes:

```
/users/12345

/users/12345/orders/12345
```

I need the second to be a child of the first, but I also need to completely replace the contents of `/users/12345` with the contents of `/users/12345/orders/12345` opposed to having `/users/12345/orders/12345` in the `/users/12345` sub `router-outlet`.

I thought I could do this by just naming the parent level router-outlet and have both routes target it, but from the research I've been doing (and the errors it caused) I get the feeling the names were intended for secondary uses when there already exists a primary router-outlet

Answer (score 33):

I had the same issue. This is how I fixed it:

```
const routes: Routes = [
   {
    path: '',
    children: [
         {
           path: '',
           component: ParentComponent,
         },
         {
           path: 'child',
           component: ChildComponent,
         }
     ]
   }
];
```

Comment: what if you have a child routing module too?

Comment: I've got to same structure but there is a problem. Parent component route is actually a sibling to child route. This makes problems for example if you need to resolve some data for parent component but also pass it to child.

Answer (score 28):

You can do it by setting your routes like this :

```
const routes : Routes = [
  { 
    path : 'user/:id',
    component : ParentComponent,
    children : [
      { path : '', component : UserComponent },
      { path : 'order/:id', component : OrderComponent }
    ]
  }
]
```

`ParentComponent`'s template will have only the `<router-outlet>` to load its children.

Answer (score 15):

If you need to hide something (like a datagrid, or instruction panel) based upon a child route being active you can simply use this:

```
<div *ngIf="outlet.isActivated == false">
   Please select a child route!
</div>

<router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
```

It is important to include [`#outlet="outlet"`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet) with the quotes because you're exporting a template variable reference.

There are also events on `router-outlet` for activation and deactivation.

An alternative is to [get the child route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38672432/angular2-rc4-check-active-child-route-in-parent-component) when the `NavigationEnd` event occurs, and then make decisions what to show or hide. For simpler cases the first approach should work fine.

Also not relevant to your question I don't think, but you can completely hide a `router-outlet` with an `*ngIf` as you would anything else.

Comment: This worked for me but I have multiple sections and i want to hide/show them. Hide/show basically switches back and forth between parent and child component. i have parent (section 1, 2, and 3). however, when section 1 loads child component , then section 1 of parent component hides as you said. Now i need to do same for section 2 and 3. Now i see that section 1 is getting affected by 2 , as outlet is common. is there a way around this ? Thanks

Comment: @kuldeep It might not be acceptable for you or anyone facing the same problem, but in my case, I had a wrapper component for each section, so each had its own outlet.

Answer (score 5):

*edit*:  I've come up with a new solution revolving around using template directives that allows for setting up routes hierarchically opposed to at the same level.

The sample code/demo can be found here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-page-layout

Updated version (2019):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-page-layout-cnjpz8

Comment: What about my answer ? Is it not what you're looking for ?

Comment: Using your example, the question was regarding how to replace 'ParentComponent' with 'OrderComponent' when on 'order/:id' in router-outlet, which that setup would not accomplish

Comment: Hi, @John. This is a brilliant solution! But how do you navigate to another route same level as the primary? It would cause an error of "Cannot read property 'createEmbeddedView' of undefined"

Comment: If the situation is both routes set 'component: PageLevelComponent' and angular is re-using the existing component from the first route, I'm not sure.  I'm sure we'll run into the same issue once we get more pages situated this way

Comment: Thank you, John. This is working so nicely for me, so far. Have you made any improvements to this? I hope to use it extensively, so would appreciate any updates. One thing I had to do, was wrap the `renderContainer` view lines in an `if (stack.length)` check. But thanks, I can't believe this is not a bigger issue for Angular routing!

Comment: @Sean - It looks like my current implementation is quite a bit different:  I'll try and post an updated version when I have a moment

Comment: @John - just a nudge. If you're able to provide an update, that would be suprt helpful.

Comment: @Sean - I updated the answer with a link containing the version I currently use

Answer (score 4):

```
 let routes = [
  { 
    path: 'users/:id',
    component: UsersComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'users/:id/orders/:id',
    component: OrdersComponent
  }
 ];
```

Comment: This solution has some tricky problems, because if there's a component-specific service, say `UserService` provided in `UsersComponent`, it won't be available to `OrdersComponent` because it isn't a child of `UsersComponent`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. This is how I fixed it:

```
const routes: Routes = [
   {
       path: 'parent',
       component: ParentComponent,
   },
   {
       path: 'parent',
       children: [
            {
                path: 'child',
                component: ChildComponent,
            }
       ],
   },
];
```

This way the `router-outlet` will use the correct component and preserve the idea of parent-child relation.

The downside of this approach is that if you need to pass data from the parent to the child you would probably need to fetch it from a service or something similar or duplicate some sort of resolver in both parent paths.