# How to get active child route in parent component Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to check the active child route in parent component but I don't know how to get this. I am trying to use `ActivatedRoute` but not able to get it.

I have tried both of the answers from [Angular2 (rc4) - Check active child route in parent component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38672432/angular2-rc4-check-active-child-route-in-parent-component?noredirect=1&lq=1):

1. I have tried the accepted answer:

   ```
   constructor(
       private router:Router,
       private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {
        var state = this.router.routerState
        var children = state.children(this.route)
    }
   ```

   With this I am getting this error:

   ```
   Property 'children' does not exist on type 'RouterState'
   ```
2. I have tried with this one as well:

   ```
   this.router.events.filter(evt => evt instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .map(evt => evt.url)
      .subscribe(url => console.log(url));
   ```

   but getting these error with this one:

   ```
   property 'url' does not exist on type 'Event'
   property 'url' does not exist on type 'RouteConfigLoadStart'`
   ```

Any idea?

Comment: yes I am trying that solution but it's not working

Comment: No tried with that as well..  not working.

Comment: getting these 2 error with that solution ... 1. `property 'url' does not exist on type 'Event'`  2. `property 'url' does not exist on type 'RouteConfigLoadStart'`

Comment: yup i have done that

Comment: That seems to be a problem with your typing, as `NavigationEnd` definitely *does* have a `.url` property; see https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationEnd. What if you explicitly type it as a `RouterEvent`?

Comment: Yeah I checked that .. No idea what the issue is.. using the same `NavigationEnd`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would say Angular (via TypeScript) is just being very type strict. You can work around it... Here is a brief example of just getting the name/path of the immediate child route.

```
this.router.events.filter(evt => evt instanceof NavigationEnd)
        .subscribe((event) => {
            console.log(event['url']);
            console.log(this.route.firstChild.routeConfig.path);
        });
```

Answer (score 5):

There's an overload to RxJS `filter` that makes it into a typeguard. The output then becomes an actual `NavigationError` object instead of just being a `RouterEvent`.

```
   this.router.events.pipe(filter((e): e is NavigationEnd => e instanceof NavigationEnd));
```

Anything after this in your `pipe(...)` will be of type `NavigationEnd` and *will* have `url` on it.

I recommend creating a helper service called something like `RouterEventsService` and creating common observables on it that you can use from anywhere.

Just a simple service like this:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class RouterEventsService
{
    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    // navigation lifetime
    navigationStart$ = this.router.events.pipe(filter((e): e is NavigationStart => e instanceof NavigationStart));
    navigationEnd$ = this.router.events.pipe(filter((e): e is NavigationEnd => e instanceof NavigationEnd));

    // you can add clever things to it as needed
    navigationDurationMs$ = this.navigationStart$.pipe(switchMap(() => 
    {
        const startTime = new Date().getTime();
        return this.navigationEnd$.pipe(take(1), map(() => new Date().getTime() - startTime));
    }), 
    shareReplay(1));
}
```

Comment: all you need is   `filter((event: NavigationEnd) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),`  to take advantage of the typeguard this answer mentions

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to import rxjs

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
```